# Linkedin: Expired access token after renew

Tags: linkedin-api

I am using Linkedin Javascript SDKs and it was all working fine, but as per Linkedin policy we need to renew the token after every 60 days, so previous 2 times renew was successful (renewed after 55 days, before 60th day), but this time I forgot to renew it & it got expired, now if I am renewing it, it gets renewed I am getting access token but on using SDK it's giving me `(401) Expired access token`